# Excluir sección en plantilla blade de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

estoy iniciando con laravel y tengo un problema con las platillas blade , yo cree un archivo al que llame **plantilla.blade.php** , en el cual pongo el **encabezado** el **cuerpo** y el **pie** de pagina , luego en mi vista **inicio.blade** quiero mostrar **el cuerpo y el pie** , pero ahi esta el problema porque tambien me muestra el **encabezado** el cual yo no quiero mostrar ni tampoco llame entonces no se porque se muestra el encabezado también

aqui les muestro el código de mis archivos.

**platilla.blade.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**inicio.blade.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me muestra el navegador , solo llame al cuerpo y pie , pero tambien me muestra el encabezado(donde dice **menu** es **pie**).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la plantilla estas agregando el yield "encabezado", ( o sea que ya lo tiene). Y luego estas usando esta plantilla para generar el inicio. (o sea que tambien lo estas incluyendo!). Deberias generar una archivo de plantilla2.blade.php que no contenga el encabezado, y usar ese para generar el inicio.

Comment: Pensaba que solo se agregarían al **inicio.blade.php** los **yield** que yo llamara a travez de los **seticion** en inicio , es decir , que como solo llamaba al cuerpo y el pie solo se deberian agregar esos 2 , pero ya entiendo que hereda toda la platilla y me la mostrara todos los **yield** asi no agregue el section('Encabezado') , por lo cual se me genera otra pregunta  , cual es la funcion del section si de igual manera me va a mostrar todos lo yield asi no ponga el section('encabezado').

Answer (score 0):

Si no deseas que aparezca no le pongas texto después de @yield('Encabezado'), ya que si le pones estarías indicando que todas las páginas que hereden de tu plantilla tienen ese texto y por eso lo mostrarían.

Pero en ocasiones las páginas tienen secciones que no cambian como el "footer" en ese caso si convendría ponerle texto después de @yield('pie'), de ese modo todas las páginas que hereden mostrarán el texto que indiques después de @yield('pie').